# How can I make my img on the footer responsive?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my img in the footer section responsive starting from a Ipad landscape view-mode till a 27 mac inch view-mode. 
And an important detail here is that I want it between my Google maps and the form section.

I've tried positioning it absolute and I am able to get it in between google maps and the form section. However on the right side there is an empty space which can be scrolled to. 
See the website to get a good idea of what I am talking about. 
I don't want anything to be able to be scrolled to the sides. The IMG should cover the full width for every mentioned screen-view mode.

www.fantazihuis.be

HTML

```
<footer>
    <img src="images/footer.png" alt="Fantazihuis footer" />
</footer>
```

CSS

```
    footer{
    margin-bottom: -130px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;}


footer img{
    width: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create media querys. You set a max width resolution for a media query and give each resolution an own style sheet:

Example:

```
@media (min-width: 30em) and (max-width: 60em) { 
    footer { 
        margin-bottom: -60px; 
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        width: 100%; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I am already aware that I should make media queries. 
You've given me almost the same data for the footer section, which I already have. 
As I've stated before, this is not responsive.
E.g. with a screen with of 1200px, you can scroll to the right side of the website which is basically empty. 
I don't want it to be scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

For some crazy reason my browser wasn't showing it correctly. 
After I synced my local files with the files I have online through my ftp, the IMG in the footer is showing correct.

The CSS was correct in this case and didn't need any tweaking.
There was no right side that was scrollable.

However, I will still need to add the media queries in order to make the whole website including the IMG footer responsive for different screen-views.